# Postgresql sum not working as expected when it is clear

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I am solving the following Hard Leetcode SQL Question.

Link to Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/trips-and-users/
(You can directly look at the solution and understand the problem)

Question:

Trips table:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| id | client_id | driver_id | city_id | status              | request_at |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| 1  | 1         | 10        | 1       | completed           | 2013-10-01 |
| 2  | 2         | 11        | 1       | cancelled_by_driver | 2013-10-01 |
| 3  | 3         | 12        | 6       | completed           | 2013-10-01 |
| 4  | 4         | 13        | 6       | cancelled_by_client | 2013-10-01 |
| 5  | 1         | 10        | 1       | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
| 6  | 2         | 11        | 6       | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
| 7  | 3         | 12        | 6       | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
| 8  | 2         | 12        | 12      | completed           | 2013-10-03 |
| 9  | 3         | 10        | 12      | completed           | 2013-10-03 |
| 10 | 4         | 13        | 12      | cancelled_by_driver | 2013-10-03 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

Users table:

```
+----------+--------+--------+
| users_id | banned | role   |
+----------+--------+--------+
| 1        | No     | client |
| 2        | Yes    | client |
| 3        | No     | client |
| 4        | No     | client |
| 10       | No     | driver |
| 11       | No     | driver |
| 12       | No     | driver |
| 13       | No     | driver |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| Day        | Cancellation Rate |
+------------+-------------------+
| 2013-10-01 | 0.33              |
| 2013-10-02 | 0.00              |
| 2013-10-03 | 0.50              |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT request_at,
count(*) c,
sum(case when status='cancelled_by_driver' or status='cancelled_by_client' then 1 else 0 end) s,
round(sum(case when status='cancelled_by_client' or status='cancelled_by_client' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*),2) as Cancellation_rate 
FROM trips 
WHERE 
    client_id not in (select users_id from users where banned = 'Yes') 
    AND 
    driver_id not in (select users_id from users where banned = 'Yes')
GROUP BY request_at;
```

And the output is:

```
 request_at | c | s | cancellation_rate 
------------+---+---+-------------------
 2013-10-01 | 3 | 1 |              0.00
 2013-10-03 | 2 | 1 |              0.00
 2013-10-02 | 2 | 0 |              0.00
```

How is the cancellation_rate is 0.00 when it is clear by looking at previous columns(s/c) that it should be 0.33,0.50, 0.00.

Comment: I have not followed it all the way, but I suspect you are getting caught by integer division, `select 1/2; 0`.  In your `count` division make one of the values `numeric`; `select round(1/2::numeric, 2); 0.50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is you're only off by a typo.

In your example you are using `cancelled_by_client or cancelled_by_client`

```
round(sum(case when status='cancelled_by_client' or status='cancelled_by_client' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*),2) as Cancellation_rate
```

rather than:

```sql
.. when status='cancelled_by_driver' or status='cancelled_by_client' then ..
```

which would return:

| request_at | c | s | cancellation_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-10-01 | 3 | 1 | 0.33 |
| 2013-10-02 | 2 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 2013-10-03 | 2 | 1 | 0.50 |